# How to add svn rev number to Android APK using Gradle?

Tags: android, svn, gradle, android-studio

How do I add the subversion revision number to an Android APK file using Gradle? Ex. AppName-1.1.123.apk, where 123 is the subversion revision number. I am using Android studio.

Thanks
Markus

Comment: Did you try http://wickedsource.org/2014/02/28/svn-revision-gradle/ ?

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine even though Android Studio does not seem to understand it. There is a a lot of red and the import seems to fail, but it works.

Comment: Good! You might want to add an answer with the relevant details, in case the link becomes dead in the future.

Comment: @MarkusK Mine fails to run on the red parts, any advice? "unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft..."

Comment: I did not manage to get rid of the warnings in Android Studio, but when I run the gradle script "assemble" it still seems to work. However, AS has troubles finding the produced apk when I try to debug an app with the svn revision in the filename, so I added a product flavor without svn revision in the filename for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this dependency classpath in your root level build.gradle file's dependencies closure

```
classpath group: 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit', name: 'svnkit', version: '1.7.11'
```

It will look like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath group: 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit', name: 'svnkit', version: '1.7.11'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Now its time to make changes in your module's build.gradle file

```
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.*

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    //YOUR OTHER CONFIGURATION

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = new File(
                    output.outputFile.parent,
                    output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}."+ getSvnRevision() + ".apk"))
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    //YOUR DEPENDENCIES HERE
}

def getSvnRevision(){
    ISVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
    SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(options);
    SVNStatusClient statusClient = clientManager.getStatusClient();
    SVNStatus status = statusClient.doStatus(projectDir, false);
    SVNRevision revision = status.getRevision();
    return revision.getNumber();
}
```

I don't use SVN these days, but I have complied and run this script in my local environment with hardcoded value and it works fine for me. Let me know it works for you too.

Comment: This code get svn number of module folder. But how to get svn number of the last commit?

Comment: @NickUnuchek, use `getCommittedRevision()` instead of `getRevision()`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code that I put in the "root" build.gradle file that solved it:

```
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.*


buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit', name: 'svnkit', version: '1.7.11'
    }
}

def getSvnRevision(){
    ISVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
    SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(options);
    SVNStatusClient statusClient = clientManager.getStatusClient();
    SVNStatus status = statusClient.doStatus(projectDir, false);
    SVNRevision revision = status.getRevision();
    return revision.getNumber();
}

allprojects {
    version = '1.2.3.' + getSvnRevision()
}
```

Comment: This code is getting svn number of module folder. But how to get svn number of the last commit?

Comment: This is very useful for reducing code redundancy in all module build.gradle files.  This way, you can simply reference "version" in all module build.gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

The code of 'pyus13' and 'Markus K' gets the current svn revision of the working copy. This is for most cases ok. But if you want to get the last revision of the server (which is may be greater as the revision of your working copy) you must get the SVN revision from the server and not from your working copy:

```
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.*
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.*
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.*
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.auth.*
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepositoryFactory;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepositoryFactory;
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl;

...

project.ext {
  svnUser = 'user'
  svnPwd = 'topsecret'
}

...

/****************************************************************************
 * Add SVN revision number to version
 ****************************************************************************/

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
      // needed for getting current SVN rev nmbr
      classpath group: 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit', name: 'svnkit', version: '1.8.14'
    }
}

/** Gets the current subversion revision number.
 */
def getSvnRevision() {
    // init needed stuff for connecting SVN server
    DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
    SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup();
    FSRepositoryFactory.setup();

    // getting SVN Url from local working copy ...
    ISVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
    SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(options);
    SVNStatusClient statusClient = clientManager.getStatusClient();
    SVNStatus status = statusClient.doStatus(projectDir, false);
    SVNURL url = status.getRepositoryRootURL();

    // connecting SVN server and getting last revision number
    SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(url);
    ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(svnUser, svnPwd);
    repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

    return repository.getLatestRevision();
}

...
```